# Cloudfoundry Eclipse Plugin error opening tunnel

Tags: eclipse, cloud-foundry

I've installing CF Eclipse plugin , but when I try to open tunnel , there is an error

```
'Open Tunnel' has encountered a problem
I/O Error:connection refused;
nested expection is java.net.ConnectionExpection:Connection refused
```

Any solusion ??

Comment: would you mind telling where are you locating?

Comment: I'll get this on error pop up , I give you an image of this

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-S_lPYr9Hwrs/UKG2jrhKQVI/AAAAAAAAAXI/OCbGc1FQaxA/s330/error_eclipse_tunnel.png

Comment: I mean your physical/internet location.

Comment: Will you be able to do that via vmc? And are you trying to target api.cloudfoundry.com or your vcap instance?

Comment: I've try it on vmc  , my cloud_controler target is paas.azure4j.us , I build it my self with chef method, and I've set up wildcard A domain for it.
When I do "vmc tunnel to <service> " an error output is :
"Connection timed out - connect(2)"
any solution ??

Comment: Did caldecott deploy successfully? can you show the output from 'vmc apps'?

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that the caldecott gem has been successfully installed so that it can be deployed when you try to tunnel. If it is possible you might want to first try tunneling to a service on api.cloudfoundry.com.